# Curve Stitching

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

Curve stitching is the process of "stitching" together multiple straight lines in order to create a curve, like so:

[image: Imgur]

For an explanation of curve stitching, visit [this website](http://nrich.maths.org/5366/index).

We will be drawing our curve in the top left of the screen, as shown in the image above.

Given an integer `n` (via STDIN or a function parameter), being the number of lines to draw, and an integer `p` pixels, being the interval between the starting points, draw a straight line curve.

Horizontal/vertical lines are necessary, and should be part of the line count.

---

#### Example Outputs:

n = 25, p = 15

[image: Imgur]

n = 20, p = 20

[image: Imgur]

---

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so **shortest code wins**.

Comment: Oh yeah! D'oh...

Comment: The curve is in fact a parabola. I can't remember where I read that thoughl. If I was a pedant I would point out that it's not a "straight line curve" but an approximation of a curve built up from straight lines :-)

Comment: @Martin Yup, pixels.

Comment: @Martin The horizontal line shouldn't be necessary, because the border of the window will make up the lines.

Comment: @Martin Whoops! The program I used to create those images was somewhat rushed. It's no huge problem though, I added the images just to make sure that everyone understood the general look of the solution.

Comment: @Martin Okay, I will fix my code and redo the examples.

Comment: @Martin Actually, just gave this some more thought, it makes more sense to have the vertical and horizontal lines required.

Comment: @JamesWilliams Will you be changing your examples to include them (since it appears that they are not included currently)?

Comment: @steveverrill Don't you mean hyperbola instead of parabola?

Comment: Oh dayum I used to do this for fun when bored in class ... didn't know other people had done the exact same thing!

Comment: @flawr I mean a parabola. See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/551882/137034 and google. If you connect two coaxial circles in 3D with strings, you get a hyperboloid of revolution. Drawing one of those in 3D could be a whole other challenge....

Comment: what if `n` is 1 - do we draw a horizontal or vertical line?

Comment: @steveverrill Oh thanks for that link! I was tricked by the rotation, but this is really neat!

Comment: @NotthatCharles The axes go from 0 to (n-1)*p, so 5,10 draws (40,0),(30,10),(20,20),(10,30),(0,40). For n=1 all you would expect to see is a dot at the origin. At least, that is what my program produces.

Comment: The curve you get is given by `x^(1/2) + y^(1/2) = const`. I don't know if there's a name for it. It's similar to the astroid curve `x^(2/3) + y^(2/3) = const` obtained by using connecting segments of constant length rather than constant x-intercept plus y-intercept.

Comment: The harder followup challenge is to draw just the segments that make up the curve.

Answer (score 6):

### Mathematica, <s>55</s> <s>51</s> <s>50</s> <s>47</s> <s>64</s> 68 bytes

```
f=Graphics[Line@Table[#2{{i-1,#+1},{0,i+1}},{i,#}],ImageSize->#*#2]&
```

Defines a function which yields the image as specified when called like

```
f[25,15]
```

Yielding

[image]

**Edit**: Had to add some characters to make sure that the second parameter was actually interpreted as pixels.

**Edit**: four more bytes to plot the horizontal lines.

Answer (score 6):

## Python - 74

Since the question doesn't specify units, axes scaling etc. I'm coming up with the following minimum solution:

```
import pylab
n,p=input()
for i in range(n):pylab.plot([0,i*p],[(i-n)*p,0])
```

[image]

Comment: Disregarding units and axis scaling, the minimum solution saves four characters by omitting `*p` ;). also, are you sure you're not adding a horizontal and/or vertical line? those are not in the example outputs. finally, I noticed in mine, that it's shorter to offset the first coordinate horizontally instead of the second one (because you can save the `-` and the parentheses)

Comment: (The question does specify units as pixels now, btw.)

Answer (score 4):

## Bash+Imagemagick+xview, 124 bytes

```
for((;i<$1;));{
s+=" -draw 'line $[i*$2],0 0,$[($1-i++)*$2]'"
}
eval convert -size $[$1*$2]x$[$1*$2] xc:$s png:-|xview stdin
```

#### Output for `./curvestitch.sh 25 15`:

[image]

Comment: Yay for overflowing the maximum command line length if you're not careful. Nice one

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), 26 bytes

```apl
{P5.G.ln↓⍉↑⍵×⍺∘-@3⍳¨⍺1 1⍺}
```

-2 bytes from Adam using *magic*

Requires `⎕IO←0`. (0-indexing)

### Explanation

```apl
{P5.G.ln↓⍉↑⍵×⍺∘-@3⍳¨⍺1 1⍺}
 P5.G.ln                   Create lines using the following sets of four points:
                    ⍺1 1⍺  Array [n,1,1,n]
                  ⍳¨       generate range 0..n for each
                           [0..n,0,0,0..n]
                @3         to the third element,
             ⍺∘-           subtract it from n.(reversing the last range)
                           [0..n,0,0,n..0]
           ⍵×              scale all items by p
          ↑                mix , creating columns of coordinates.
        ↓⍉                 transpose, and convert to lists of two points
```

### [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), 28 bytes

```apl
{P5.G.ln↓⍉↑(⍵×⍳⍺)⍬⍬(⍵×⍺-⍳⍺)}
```

Anonymous function which takes n and p as left and right arguments, and displays the pattern, given an adequately sized canvas.

Full Program [here.](https://dzaima.github.io/paste/#0y3vUNsGMqwBImhtxBZjqFWdWpQI5Ro96t@Qdnl7AxZUG5FUXAYlHvVsfdbdUA9W46@XkaRQdng4U0VQwAEIIZ5cuSKD20IpHvZuBvFqFR71zFULz0vNz0lJTFNJK85JLMvPzuLjSQSZCjXnUNvlRb@ejtokaQL0gQ0A6NR/1rgEimBDIXLAwxEQM80CuTi0pBfmhmksBCECq8hTSFArAvDyFdCCrFgA#dAPL18)

Made with a lot of advice and golfing from dzaima.

#### Test Cases

`25, 15`

[image]

`20, 20`

[image]

`6,72`

[image]

### [Java + `Processing`](http://openjdk.java.net/), 62 bytes

The original function I made for this question.

```java
void c(int n,int p){for(int i=1;i<n;)line(p*i,0,0,p*(n-i++));}
```

Comment: Does `{P5.G.ln↓⍉↑⍵×⍺-@3⍳¨⍺1 1⍺}` work?

Comment: @Adám `IncorrectArgsError: @ can't be called dyadically`

Comment: OK, but then you have the choice between `{P5.G.ln↓⍉↑⍵×⍺∘-@3⍳¨⍺1 1⍺}` and `{P5.G.ln↓⍉↑⍵×(⍳⍺)⍬⍬(⍺-⍳⍺)}`

Comment: @Adám Added an explanation, hope it's correct.

Comment: Almost: `⍵×` is a scaling applied to everything, not just item 3.

Answer (score 4):

### Basic 7.0, Commodore 128, <del>60</del> 58 bytes

```
0inputn,p:gR1:s=n*p:do:dR1,s,0to0,n:s=s-p:n=n+p:loOwHs>=0
```

Watch a video of it running:

[image: C128 video]

Unfortunately, INPUT command hasn't an abbreviation :(

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, <del>121</del> 130 bytes

The input is via `STDIN`. The values are comma separated.

**EDIT:** We have new rules. I'm not sure why, but the first two pixels are invisible and I had to add an offset...

```perl
use Tk;<>=~/,/;$c=tkinit->Canvas(-width=>$w=$`*$'-$',-height=>$w)->pack;$c->createLine(2,2+$_*$',2+$w-$_*$',2)for 0..~-$`;MainLoop
```

Here are some tests:

**25x15:**

[image: 25x15]

**6x72:**

[image: 6x72]

Answer (score 3):

## BBC Basic, 58 ascii characters, tokenised filesize 49

```
INPUTn,p:p*=2FORi=1TOn:MOVEi*p-p,974DRAW0,974-(n-i)*p:NEXT
```

Download emulator at http://www.bbcbasic.co.uk/bbcwin/bbcwin.html

`p*=2` is needed because in the default mode BBC Basic maps a logical square of 2x2 to a single physical pixel.

BBC Basic has the origin at the bottom left corner of the screen, with y coorinates going up. On my machine the default window has an upper y coordinate of 974 (yours may be different.) 7 characters could be saved if it was permitted to plot in the bottom left corner of the screen. Adding `MODE16` after the first `:` will resize the window so that the upper y coordinate is guaranteed to be 799.

[image]

Comment: This is fast becoming a dangerous golfing language. CJam who?

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 143 bytes

```java
import java.awt.*;n->p->new Frame(){{add(new Panel(){public void paint(Graphics g){for(int m=0;m<n;)g.drawLine(0,m*p,n*p-++m*p,0);}});show();}}
```

**Output for \$n=25, p=15\$:**

[image]

**Output for \$n=5, p=50\$:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.awt.*;            // Required import for almost everything
n->p->                        // Method with two integer parameters & Frame return-type
  new Frame(){                //  Create the Frame
   {                          //   In an inner code-block:
     add(new Panel(){         //    Add a Panel we can draw on:
       public void paint(Graphics g){
                              //     Overwrite its paint method:
         for(int m=0;m<n;)    //      Loop `m` in the range [0,n):
           g.drawLine(        //       Draw a line:
             0,m*p,           //        Starting at x=0, y=m*p
             n*p-++m*p,0);}});//        to x=n*p-(m+1)*p, y=0
     show();}};               //    And afterwards show the Frame
```

Comment: I think it specifies that vertical and horizontal lines are necessary where it says "Horizontal/vertical lines are necessary, and should be part of the line count." (or am I misunderstanding you?)

Comment: @thedefault. Fixed. And it turned out even 2 bytes shorter. :) Thanks again for noticing.

Comment: I don't know java, but where in the code do you specify the output pixels?  When I look at your 2 examples, they seem to be 305 & 176 pixels across, which is less than 25*15 & 5*50.  Or is this just a side-effect of the up-/downloading?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen The width/height is actually \$(n-1)\times p\$, so 360 for the first test case and 200 for the second. But if the pictures shows something different it's probably an issue of automatic cropping when making a screenshot, uploading it to imgur, or showing it at stackexchange. I don't see it mentioning `pixels` in particular in the `drawLine` method (it uses `Graphics` coordinate system, but no idea what it uses by default). Tbh, I have no idea why my screenshots appear smaller than some other answers for the \$n=25,p=15\$ test case, but the calculations are correct with n & p..

Comment: Ah, I kind-of assumed that the screenshot/upload/imgur/SE chain was to blame!  So if your graphs are the correct sizes on your computer, I take it that the 'graphics' coordinates are defined as 1 coordinate = 1 pixel, which is quite convenient here!

Answer (score 1):

## Html + JavaScript 155 <s>157 183</s>

Edit: learnig what stuff I can cut without functionality loss
Edit 2: as suggested by @Optimizer

```
<canvas id='c'/><script>
p=prompt,s=p(l=p(t=c.getContext("2d")));for(c.width=c.height=y=s*l,x=0;l--;x-=s)t.moveTo(0,y-=s),t.lineTo(-x,0);t.stroke()
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ke43m7c/7/embedded/result/) First input *number of lines*, second input *pixel interval*

[Ungolfed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ke43m7c/1/)

Comment: l=p(s=p(t=c.getContext("2d")))

Comment: @Optimizer I think I need to set width and height before getting the context

Comment: Nope, this works : http://jsfiddle.net/6ke43m7c/10/

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 100 bytes

```r
function(n,p,P=p*n*1.08){bmp(,P,P)
par(mar=!1:4)
plot.new()
segments((1:n-1)/n,1,0,1:n/n)
dev.off()}
```

Saves output to bitmap file 'Rplot001.bmp'.
There are some 'wasted' pixels at the top & on the left (so the curve is in the top left corner but not touching the edge).
This seems to be within the spec, but could be removed for +13 bytes.

Commented code:

```r
curve_stitch=
function(n,p,                   # n = number of lines, p = pixels between starting points
 P=p*n*1.08){                   # P = pixel dimensions of final plot.  
                                # (R expands axes by 4% at each end by default, so to 
                                # ensure that the curve itself is p*n pixels, we need 
                                # to expand the output by +8%
 bmp(,P,P)                      # open bitmap output to default filename, with dimensions PxP
 par(mar=!1:4)                  # remove margins by setting all to zero
 plot.new()                     # define new plot (default data range from 0 to 1)
 segments((1:n-1)/n,1,0,1:n/n)  # plot lines within range from 0 to 1
 dev.off()                      # close bitmap output to save file
 }
```

Sample output:

```r
curve_stitch(10,10)
```

[image]

```r
curve_stitch(5,50)
```

[image]